# C++ Alternative to Private Virtual functions that can be called in a derived class

Tags: c++, oop

According to Herb Sutter:

> Guideline #2: Prefer to make virtual functions private.
>
> This lets the derived classes override the function to customize the
> behavior as needed, without further exposing the virtual functions
> directly by making them callable by derived classes (as would be
> possible if the functions were just protected). The point is that
> virtual functions exist to allow customization; unless they also need
> to be invoked directly from within derived classes' code, there's no
> need to ever make them anything but private

But happens if you need to call this private virtual method in the derived class?  Lets say, in your derived class, it needs to extend what the base class does, and thus requiring a function call to the private virtual helper method.    Is there an alternative way to design your class, such that this is possible?
Thanks.

Comment: "_...(as would be possible if the functions were just protected.).."_

Comment: *"unless they also need to be invoked directly from within derived classes' code"* - Seems you have a need, so why are you fretting about the guideline?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm not worrying about the guideline, I'm wondering what's the alternative design since my criteria doesn't match the guideline

Comment: It is not uncommon for a derived class to call the base class virtual function before or after doing something in addition.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @ruisen It seems like your use case does match the guidelines (it sounds like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QghlSJK2QrPlDy56). If not, can you give some example code for what you want to do? (Also, the virtual function itself shouldn't be a helper, it should call another non-virtual function that is the helper to avoid virtual lookup)

Comment: @Artyer It does not match, because the private virtual function in the base class cannot be called in the derived class.  It can only be invoked from the base class.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's a good idea